# Select2 onchange select option then append or strip url depending on option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

Currently I have a `select` dropdown filter setup via php like this:

```
<?php if($this->config->get("config_show_tmall_only")){?>
  <?php if(isset($code) && $code=="tmall"){?>
  <select id="tmallFilter">
    <option value="&code=tmall">Tmall only</option>
    <option value="">Taobao &amp; Tmall</option>
  </select>
  <?php }else{?>
  <select id="tmallFilter">
    <option value="">Taobao &amp; Tmall</option>
    <option value="&code=tmall">Tmall only</option>
  </select>
  <?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

It detects if `&code=tmall` is in the url and runs the first block

I am appending `&code=tmall` through this script that runs exactly how I need

```
$('#tmallFilter').bind('change', function () {
    var brwsr_url=document.URL;
    var redirecturl= brwsr_url + $(this).val();
    location.href = redirecturl;
});
```

The problem I am running into is when i need to go back to `Taobao & Tmall` I can only add to the url, not strip characters based on that select.

Is there any way I can strip `&code=tmall` from the url when I select the `Taobao &amp; Tmall` option?

Answer (score 0):

This is to strip away `&code=tmall` specifically using [`String.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
$('#tmallFilter').bind('change', function () {
    var brwsr_url = document.URL;
    var redirecturl= brwsr_url.replace(/&code=tmall/, '') + $(this).val();
    location.href = redirecturl;
});
```